# Recording an online video stream

Tags: recording, video-streaming

A friend of mine defends his PhD in a few days. The ceremony will be streamed live here: `http://131.174.53.158`. It's a constant live stream of what happens in that university facility. Unfortunately they do not record their stream and my friend would really like to have a recording of his defence.

How can I record it for him, I haven't got a clue about streaming technology?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I looked at the stream requested by the streaming applet, it seems the video URL is the following:
`rtsp://131.174.53.158:554/axis-media/media.amp?videocodec=h264&camera=1&streamprofile=Balanced`. The last parameter is customizable with the other selectable options like 'Quality', 'Bandwidth', etc. You then need a program that can capture **RTSP video streams**, google should help there. You probably need to try a few until one works.

I just tried VLC, it can view the stream just fine, but when you try to save it, it just saves garbage data.

Good luck!

**Edit:** Here is how I found the URL. The hardest part was actually getting the stream to work in any browser the regular way. It finally worked on windows with the quicktime plugin installed for firefox. Then I used Wireshark to sniff all traffic from my PC to the website in question. You now have all information you need about the stream. You just have to find it.

First thing I did was filter all recorded packages for the IP adress given: `ip.addr == 131.174.53.158`.

The next thing I noticed was that the communication changes from http to rtsp as soon as the quicktime plugin loads. This looks like this:

[image: http to rtsp change]

So the information had to be shortly before or after this point (Because I found nothing before that, and only raw video data was following). Turns out there is a RTSP packet `Reply: RTSP/1.0 200 OK, with session description` that contains all our infos:

[image: rtsp session info packet]

Et voilà! (Agreed, you probably have to know a bit about network protocols to find your way around wireshark. But it's actually not that bad.)

Comment: Wow, just for the record, how did you figure out this url? I just tried recording with VLC and I didn't get garbage but a nice 20 seconds of recording :). Thanks!

Comment: Ah, great that it works for you! I used Wireshark to sniff the traffic going to this site. It actually took me a while until I started looking at the rtsp packages not the http ones. I guess I can edit my answer and show you.

Comment: Well, that's a great answer and not trivial at all. I've got wireshark installed but I didn't think of using it for this for one second...

Answer (score 2):

It seems the site uses custom Java and ActiveX controls to present the stream. The stream is over http without encryption, but you'll still need specialist software to pull that. I guess the easiest thing is to get a screen recorder like VLC or Camtesia to record it.